# angular 8 array change in console but not in view

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

Hello community i'm new to angular and i'm trying to make a pagination component with logic, at this point i'm successfully getting the correct array in the console but in the view it is not changing.

i'm able to move through pages correctly only the pagination component itself is not changing.
[pagination view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et9mt.png)

the console i get when i navigate through the pages:

```
pagination.component.ts:25 (10) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
pagination.component.ts:25 (10) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
pagination.component.ts:25 (10) [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
pagination.component.ts:25 (10) [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
pagination.component.ts:25 (10) [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

this is the function in the service that create the array that show correctly on console but not in the view.

```
initialPagination(totalPages: number) {
    this.pagination = [];
    this.numberOfPages = totalPages
    if (this.numberOfPages <= 10) {
      // less than 10 total pages so show all
      this.startPage = 1;
      this.endPage = this.numberOfPages;
    } else {
      // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
      if (this.pageToShow <= 6) {
        this.startPage = 1;
        this.endPage = 10;
      } else if (this.pageToShow + 4 >= this.numberOfPages) {
        this.startPage = this.numberOfPages - 9;
        this.endPage = this.numberOfPages;
      } else {
        this.startPage = this.pageToShow - 5;
        this.endPage = this.pageToShow + 4;
      }
    }

    // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
    for (let i = this.startPage; i < this.endPage + 1; i++) {
      this.pagination.push(i)
    }
    return this.pagination
}
```

over here is the component itself

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li (click)="replacePage(pagination.pageToShow - 1)"><a>&laquo;</a></li>
<li (click)="replacePage(i)" [ngClass]="{active:pagination.pageToShow === i}"
    *ngFor="let page of pager; let i = index"><a>{{i + 1}}</a></li>
<li (click)="replacePage(pagination.pageToShow + 1)"><a>&raquo;</a></li>
```

and here is the initialization of the pagination:

```
  replacePage(page: number) {
    if (page >= 0) {
      if (page < this.numberOfPages) {
        this.pagination.pageToShow = page;
        this.pager = this.pagination.initialPagination(this.numberOfPages)
        console.log(this.pager)
      }
    }
  }
```

why iis the view not update but console is?

Comment: This is quite unclear. Please post all the relevant code, and tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen expected output, in the view on in the console), and the actual output (in the view and in the console). Stackblitz is your friend.

Comment: i added some more information i hope it better clear things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view loops through the elements of `pager`, and displays the **index** of each element. And whenever you click, you change the **elements** of pager, but pager is still an array of 10 elements, with indices thus still going from 0 to 9.

You need to display the **elements** of the array, rather than its **indices**.

Comment: thank you so much. i will notice those thing better next time